# Curl is working but ping is not working when specify an interface

Tags: routing, ip, ping

Running on Fedora 25 in a virtualBox, I attached 2 network cards with NAT configuration.

I can see both interfaces and routes are automatically created by the system:

```
$ ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100 
default via 10.0.3.2 dev enp0s8  proto static  metric 101 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100 
10.0.3.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.3.15  metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Now I would like to make curl requests through both interfaces:

```
$ curl --interface enp0s3 www.perdu.com
<html><head><title>Vous Etes Perdu ?</title></head><body><h1>Perdu sur l'Internet ?</h1><h2>Pas de panique, on va vous aider</h2><strong><pre>    * <----- vous &ecirc;tes ici</pre></strong></body></html>
$ curl --interface enp0s8 www.perdu.com
<html><head><title>Vous Etes Perdu ?</title></head><body><h1>Perdu sur l'Internet ?</h1><h2>Pas de panique, on va vous aider</h2><strong><pre>    * <----- vous &ecirc;tes ici</pre></strong></body></html>
```

But when I would like to ping through both interfaces, only one is working:

```
$ ping -Ienp0s3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.2.15 enp0s3: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=4.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=5.49 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.874/5.182/5.490/0.308 ms
$ ping -Ienp0s8 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 10.0.3.15 enp0s8: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2079ms
```

My question is how can I make ping working through both interfaces?

Thank you

Comment: This could be related to the *arp flux* in linux. Try to `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2` in the VM. Then clear the arp caches on your host, it might also be that you have to wait a few seconds. If that helps, add `net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2` to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-my.conf` to make it reboot persistent.

Comment: I applied your command and then cleared the cache with `ip -s -s neigh flush all` but this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Your solution works. I had just to apply it to `net.ipv4.conf.enp0s8.rp_filter=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to the *arp flux* in linux. Try to

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
```

in the VM. Then clear the *arp* caches on your host, it might also be that you have to wait a few seconds. If that helps, add

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2
```

to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-my.conf` to make it reboot persistent. After a reboot it shouldn't be necessary to apply that to each single interface.